# Is there a difference between using npm and node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm using npm to download libraries.
Is it correct to say that I'm using node.js ?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "using".

Comment: Well, I have to explain how my website has been build in class. I have used npm command line to install vue.js and other dependencies. Not sure if installing dependencies from npm is using node.js

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NPM` is a package manager for `Node.js` packages, or modules.
`NPM` hosts thousands of free packages to download and use.
The `NPM` program is installed on your computer when you install `Node.js`

`Node.js` As an asynchronous event-driven JavaScript runtime, Node.js is designed to build scalable network applications.
https://nodejs.org/en/about/

`Node.js` is all about modularity, and with that comes the need for a quality package manager; for this purpose, npm was made. With **`npm`** comes the largest selection of community-created packages of any programming ecosystem, which makes building `Node.js` apps quick and easy.
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/meta/topics/dependencies/#npm

Hope I helped you see the differences.Best Regards !

Answer (score 0):

Yes nodejs is a runtime environment for javascript [docs here](https://nodejs.org/en/about/) like JRE is for java. You can use Node to run javascript in you system otherwise you need a browser to run it

---

NPM is a library for javascript [read here](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-npm), you use that to install libraries incase you need to use some extra features you dont wanna code yourself

Nodejs can run w/o use of npm like you can use other library repo like yarn likewise you can use other run time environment like Deno and use npm with that w/o using node